# How do i send a receipt validation request to apple via JSON POST?

Tags: php, ios, json, api, app-store

I have seen a few questions of this, but none really fix my issue, where I get a response of {"status":21002}

My PHP code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('receipt-data' => $receipt)));

print curl_exec($curl);
print curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

here are my raw HTTP headers going to apple:

```
POST /verifyReceipt HTTP/1.1
Host: sandbox.itunes.apple.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3382
Expect: 100-continue
```

The value of $receipt is :

```
{"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox","app_item_id":0,"original_purchase_date": ....
```

I won't include the whole thing but it includes the in-app field.

I have also tried to `base64_encode` or `json_decode` $receipt, but i get the same response. Except that `base64_encode` also gets me `"exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"`

I am sure the posting is correct, but am I sending the wrong contents? is the $receipt supposed to be wrapped with other data? or should i just send a subset of this data?

Answer (score 0):

From the value of your `$receipt` parameter, it appears that you are mixing local and server receipt validation. According to the receipt validation guide, and specifically the [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) section, the receipt-data parameter should be the "base64 encoded receipt data." Instead of decoding the receipt data on the client, simply base64 encode the receipt data as a string, and use that for `$receipt`.

I'd find it simpler to base64 encode the receipt data on the client side, then send that to the php. Here's a condensed version from the doc examples, and since you're talking iTunes store receipt, I'm hoping the obj-c is what you need. To get this string, retrieve the receipt data url, read the data out from it, then base64 encode it:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *encoded = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

The POST does look correct otherwise.